# problem dealing with a function based scenario

Tags: javascript, function, if-statement, boolean

I'm doing a course to learn the basics of javascript

I'm currently on the functions chapter and have no idea why my code doesnt work, I have even checked with chatGPT which says my code looks good and should run as expected.

This is the scenario;

Declare a function called checkIfHealthyColony.

The function should take two parameters:

colony - represents an array of objects, each one of which represents an individual ant. Each ant object contains a name property and a type property. If the ant is infected, the type property of the ant object will contain the value zombie

hasAntidote - represents a boolean which determines if we have an antidote to remove the infection!

Our function should return true if none of the ants are zombies, or hasAntidote is true. Otherwise, the health of the colony is compromised and the function should return false.

This is the example array given;

```
const exampleColony = [
    {
        name: "anthony",
        type: "worker"
    },
    {
        name: "dec",
        type: "worker"
    },
    {
        name: "marie-antoinette",
        type: "queen"
    },
    {
        name: "adam",
        type: "zombie"
    }
];
```

This is my code;

```
function checkIfHealthyColony(colony, hasAntidote) {
  for (const ant of colony) {
    if (ant.type === 'worker' || hasAntidote === true) {
      return true; // The colony is healthy
    }
  }
  return false; // The colony is not healthy
}
```

And this is the feedback im getting;
2 Passing
1 Failing

should return false when a zombie is found and there is no antidote

✕ AssertionError: expected true to equal false

should return true when a zombie is found but there is an antidote

```
✓  Well done!
```

should return true when no zombie is found

```
✓  Well done!
```

When i put colony.type instead of ant.type the first criteria turns correct but the last goes incorrect, my head is exploding HELP

Comment: Your code does not check the "zombie" case at all; it has to distinguish between "queen" and "zombie".

Comment: Your function returns true if any of the ants are workers, not if *all* of the ants are workers.

Comment: There's no need to check for the antidote in the loop, it won't change. Check that first.

Answer (score 1):

Your function returns true if any of the ants are workers. But there could still be another ant that's a zombie, or they're all queens and drones, it won't check for that. You need to reverse the sense of the test.

You should check `hasAntidote` outside the loop, since it's not dependent on the ant.

```
function checkIfHealthyColony(colony, hasAntidote) {
  if (hasAntidote) {
    return true;
  }
  for (const ant of colony) {
    if (ant.type === 'zombie') {
      return false; // The colony is unhealthy
    }
  }
  return true;
}
```

There's also a built-in array method `some()` that will perform the loop for you.

```js
function checkIfHealthyColony(colony, hasAntidote) {
  return hasAntidote || !colony.some(ant => ant.type == 'zombie');
}

console.log(checkIfHealthyColony(exampleColony, true));
console.log(checkIfHealthyColony(exampleColony, false));
console.log(checkIfHealthyColony(exampleColony2, false));
```

```html
<script>
  const exampleColony = [{
      name: "anthony",
      type: "worker"
    },
    {
      name: "dec",
      type: "worker"
    },
    {
      name: "marie-antoinette",
      type: "queen"
    },
    {
      name: "adam",
      type: "zombie"
    }
  ];
  const exampleColony2 = [{
      name: "anthony",
      type: "worker"
    },
    {
      name: "dec",
      type: "worker"
    },
    {
      name: "marie-antoinette",
      type: "queen"
    },
    {
      name: "adam",
      type: "drone"
    }
  ];
</script>
```